# Multiple directories pushing

Tags: php, github, ftp, opencart

I have multiple sites with CMS OpenCart, each of these sites have the same controllers / views / models, but hosted in different directories. I am looking for a solution to push changed file to all directories at the same time when I have a change file

folders looks like that (inside one FTP):

```
abakan.apple-wild.com
ekb.apple-wild.com
moscow.apple-wild.com
and more...
```

Comment: Do you use OC multistore?

Comment: No, OC version 2.3 :(

Comment: Use Multistore.

Answer (score 0):

You know opencart supports multiple stores natively with just one installation.